# Add commas and decimal points in Shiny Export?

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently working on a shiny app to calculate costs and I was wondering what would be the best approach to include comas and two decimal points to the cost? I've tried adding format but that just yielded errors.
Following is my server code:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  output$cost<- renderText({
    A <- as.numeric(input$a)
    B <- as.numeric(input$b)
    C <- as.numeric(input$c)
    paste("Your total cost is $", C * ((A * 75.50) + (B * 35.95)))
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `format` function:

```
paste("Your total cost is $", format(C * ((A * 75.50) + (B * 35.95)), big.mark = ",", decimal.mark = ".", nsmall = 2))
```

**Update:** I assume you want two decimal places, add `nsmall = 2`.

Comment: Worked like a charm, I was using the format function but I think I placed the parameters wrong. Thanks!